# Deploy failed in Visual Studio 2022 Xamarin android project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

Why visual studio always fail to deployed. I need to close it to deploy, but later while using, it does not work again. Also when I Ctrl+S multiple times before deployment sometimes it works, but most of the time it does not work. It there anything I need to do for it to work?

[Console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdahb.png)

Comment: Did this occur on a new project or only for this project?

Comment: Same thing happen in different project

Comment: I don't know also the reason why it happen, because it does not show any error.

Comment: By the way it happen in both old and new project.

Comment: It is so weird. Have you check the deploy setting in Build> Configuration Manager? If it still does not work, you could try to repair the Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, it is check. Just now I updated my VS 2022 to 17.1.3, hoping it will solve the problem

Comment: Any update? Has the upgrade fixed the issue? Do you have something more to share with us?

Comment: No, it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issues. I suspect the problems started when I updated Android Studio to the latest version.

I have found some success in going into Task Manager and killing all of the running adb.exe processes and then retrying the deploy.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2022 not android studio.

Comment: Sorry, probably should've been clearer. I mean, I installed Android Studio along side Visual Studio - I use Visual Studio and have this same problem in Visual Studio. However, my troubles started when I updated Android Studio - not sure if they use the same SDK and something changed - haven't had time to investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check issue #6652 on https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android, posted Jan 19th.

You appear to have the same problem. No, fix as yet, but there is a reasonably quick workaround. Just close the solution, via the File menu and reopen it and then deploy, way faster than closing VS and opening the solution again.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, I fixed the problem by going to my registry editor
and going to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node.

When you reach this stage you might find out that the Android SDK Tools Key is missing, So you must add a key with the name "Android SDK Tools" (without the quotes)
After adding it, you must now add a key within the Android SDK Tools key file called Path (this must be added as a key). Then, you must modify the path by adding the  Android-SDK file path.

Then restart your computer and that's it. Please see the video by Codebuns (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6AElkDz9oM)

Comment: Still not working.